# Bootstrap problema "modal-backdrop fade show"

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

estoy teniendo inconvenientes con la clase **modal-backdrop show** de boostrap ya que cuando abro el modal la opacidad se posiciona por encima del modal y no permite interactuar

```
  <div  class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div  class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Carrito</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          
          <table class="table table-borderless">
            <thead>
              <tr >
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                <th scope="col">Sub-total</th>
              
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="contenedor-carrito">     <!---->
           
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
          <div class="carrito-acciones" >
            <button id="carrito-acciones-vaciar" class="carrito-acciones-vaciar btn btn-secondary">Vaciar carrito</button>
         </div>

         <div class="cont-total-pagar">
            
          <div id="total" class="carrito-acciones-total" ></div>
          <button  id="procesar-compra" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" target="blank" >Continuar</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

he intentado pisar con css pero no lo toma:

[image: print herramienta del desarrollador]

Si en este caso destilo .modal-backdrop.show{} se quita la opacidad pero he intentado pisar con el CSS pero nada:

Comment: He copiado tu código, tal cual como lo pusiste, y el backdrop funciona perfectamente. Tu problema debe estar en otro lado, quizás has pisado una regla CSS

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu recomendacion. Estube viendo y tenia un problema con el z-index. Gracias.

Comment: Fabuloso!! Si tu problema se ha solucionado, te recomiendo borrar la pregunta. Saludos